# Start up mgsbox when form loads the first time

Tags: vba, startup, msgbox

Is there a way to have a msgbox appear when form1 loads for the first time?

So if I opened the program again that msgbox would not appear.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to save a value in a cell (Let's say A1000):

```
Private Sub UserFrom1_Initialize()
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000") = "" Then
        MsgBox("Welcome to your frist time using this!")
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000") = "0"
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also store the information in a hidden worksheet, if you don't want it to be seen by everyone.